# Universal camera capture across browsers and devices

Tags: html, upload, camera, media, capture

I am building a web application that must allow the user to upload images, preferably by a device's camera. There are several techniques to do this, it seems:

- Media Capture and Streams: navigator.getUserMedia()
- Flash image capture
- HTML media capture: {input type="file" accept="image/*"capture}
- other???

The best way to handle this, would be to choose a technique based on the client device and browser. Maybe fall back to traditional file upload.

Very much like Comet handles server communications. Is there some sort if library or collection of techniques to achieve this? Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Now 2 of us are searching !